# Matching json element name to table's classname

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the content of mainObject

```js
      var mainObject={"Main":[{
   "I_Have": [
  { "typeofAcc":"casa",
   "key":"MyMainSavings",
   "MyMainSavings": {
    "MyMainSavingsTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 5,600.00",
     "Rate":""
    },
    "MyMainSavingsBottom": 
    [
     {
      "Available": "Available",
      "Value": "$4329"
     },
     {"Clear": "Clear","Value": "$3456"},
     {"Hold": "Hold","Value": "$5000"}
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "key":"MyEverydayExpenses",
   "MyEverydayExpenses": {
    "MyEverydayExpensesTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 600.00",
     "Rate":""
    },
    "MyEverydayExpensesBottom": 
    [
     {"Available": "Available","Value": "$4329"},
     {"Clear": "Clear","Value": "$3456"},
     {"Hold": "Hold","Value": "$7300"}
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "key":"FavDeposit",
   "FavDeposit": {
    "FavDepositTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 5,000.00",
     "Rate": "@4.5%"
    },
    "FavDepositBottom": 
    [
     {"MaturityValue": "Maturity Value","Value": "$4009"},
     {"Term": "Term","Value": "$1156"},
     {"MaturesOn": "Matures On","Value": "$5000"}
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "key":"MyDeposit",
   "MyDeposit": {
    "MyDepositTop": {
     "AccountName": "MyMainSavings",
     "AccountNumber": "x726",
     "Balance": "USD 8,600.00",
     "Rate": "@4.5%"
    },
    "MyDepositBottom": 
    [
     {"MaturityValue": "Maturity Value","Value": "$4329"},
     {"Term": "Term","Value": "$3456"},
     {"MaturesOn": "Matures On","Value": "$5000"}
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
      },   
         {    "I_Owe" :[
   
            {"key":"HomeLoan",
   "HomeLoan":
     { 
       "HomeLoanTop":
      {
       "AccountName":"MyMainSavings",
       "AccountNumber":"x726",
       "Balance":"USD 5,600.00",
       "Rate":"@4.5% floating"
      },  
      "HomeLoanBottom":
      [
       {"Installment":"Installment","Value":"$4329" }, 
       {"Disbursed":"Disbursed","Value":"$3456" }, 
       {"CurrentDues":"Current Dues","Value":"$5000" }
      ]                 
                    }
   },    
   {"key":"Ruby",
    "Ruby":
     {
       "RubyTop":
      {
       "AccountName":"MyMainSavings",
       "AccountNumber":"x726",
       "Balance":"USD 600.00",
       "Rate":""
      },  
      "RubyBottom":
      [
       {"$6500 Dues":"$6500 Dues","Value":"$4329" }, 
       {"Minimum Due":"Minimum Due","Value":"$3456" }, 
       {"Unbilled":"Unbilled","Value":"$7300" }
      ]                 
                    }
   },
   {"key":"MyOverdraft", 
   "MyOverdraft":
     {
       "MyOverdraftTop":
      {
       "AccountName":"MyMainSavings",
       "AccountNumber":"x726",
       "Balance":"USD 5,000.00",
       "Rate":"" 
      },  
      "MyOverdraftBottom":
      [
       {"Available":"Available","Value":"$4009" }, 
       {"Unclear":"Unclear","Value":"$1156" }, 
       {"Sanc_Limit":"Sanc. Limit","Value":"$5000" }
      ]   
                    }     
   }     
  ]
         }]}
```

I am trying to traverse through json data i.e var mainObject={...} using a for loop.However I am unable to match the className of table with that of the element at which x(variable defined in for loop) is pointing.

```js
        $("<div>", {class: "wrapper"}).append(
        $("<div>", {class: "LeftSection"}).append(
            $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavings"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsTop"}).append($("<table>",{class:         "MyMainSavingsTop"})).append($(table456)),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyMainSavingsBottom"}).append($("<table>",              {class: "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "MyEverydayExpenses"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyEverydayExpensesTop"}).append($("<table>",            {class: "MyEverydayExpensesTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyEverydayExpensesBottom"}).append($("                    <table>",{class: "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "MyDeposit"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyDepositTop"}).append($("<table>",{class:               "MyDepositTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyDepositBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class:             "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "FavDeposit"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "FavDepositTop"}).append($("<table>",{class:             "FavDepositTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "FavDepositBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class:             "tablebottom"}))
   )
        ), 
        $("<div>", {class: "RightSection"}).append(
   $("<div>", {class: "HomeLoan"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "HomeLoanTop"}).append($("<table>",{class:               "HomeLoanTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "HomeLoanBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class:             "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "Ruby"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "RubyTop"}).append($("<table>",{class:                     "RubyTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "RubyBottom"}).append($("<table>",{class:                     "tablebottom"}))
   ),
   $("<div>", {class: "MyOverdraft"}).append(
    $("<div>", {class: "MyOverdraftTop"}).append($("<table>",{class:                 "MyOverdraftTop"})),
    $("<div>", {class: "MyOverdraftBottom"}).append($("<table>",                    {class: "tablebottom"}))
            )
    )).appendTo("body")
 
 
        for(var x in mainObject)
            {
 
         //if("<table>".className == Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x))
       if(mainObject.attr() == "<table>".className)
  {
   
    for(i=0; i<x.prev().length; i++)
   {
    var table123 = $("<table>");
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').text(mainObject[x]);
    var table456 = table123.append(row);
   }
      }
            }
```

Comment: What is mainObject? Why are you showing that jQuery snippet?

Comment: mainObject is the variable that holds json data.jQuery snippet is shown to give idea of ow table is being appended.

Comment: But you're not showing the mainObject contents!!